# Website deployed on AWS EC2 is different than Local version

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have deployed an Angular website using an AWS EC2 Ubuntu free Tier and I made some updates to the local version and pushed the changes to Github. I SSH into the instance on my machine and pull the updates. When I check the code on the EC2 instance the changes are reflected in the code but are not showing up in the live website.

After I pulled the changes I:

```
pm2 kill

pm2 start server.js

sudo service nginx stop && sudo service nginx start
```

I then decided to delete the repo and re-clone it into the EC2 instance and the changes still aren't there. I also cloned the repo to my machine re-installed everything just to verify the changes are on Github and they are.

What might be going on here?

Comment: I did clear the cache and tried using incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

The old mapping.js was still there I had to do an NG Build which replaced the old mapping and push the changes to Github.